# Filter URL in PHP Switch Statement

Tags: php, filter, preg-match

I wrote a Switch Statement to add custom titles to my website on pages where I want to change the default title.

It works but if a visitor goes to e.g.: google.com/cars?page=2 or google.com/cars?sort=asc the pagetitle is set to default.

How can I adjust the code below, to also show the custom page title on pages with something behind the questionmark in the URL?

```
<?php
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch ($host)
{

case "google.com":
echo 'Google';
break;

case "google.com/cars":
echo 'Cars - Google';
break;

case "google.com/bicyles":
echo 'Bicycles - Google';
break;

case "google.com/trains":
echo 'Trains - Google';
break;

default:
echo $title;
}
```

?>

Comment: parse_url and use the path

Answer (score 0):

Use parse_url (https://www.php.net/parse_url).

```
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$host = $uri['host'] . $uri['path'];
```

Please note, I have not tried this... you may need to grab the scheme (ie "http://") as well for this to work.

Comment: parse_url needs the link to have "http://" in front of it, even if you don't use the scheme.

Comment: you sure?  The manual does say: 
    On seriously malformed URLs, parse_url() may return FALSE.

However, it goes on to say:
    Example #2 A parse_url() example with missing scheme
    
    <?php
    $url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';
    
    // Prior to 5.4.7 this would show the path as "//www.example.com/path"
    var_dump(parse_url($url));
    ?>

Like I said... have not tried it, so you may be right.

Comment: Hmm... seems to be dependent on the PHP version: 5.4.7  Fixed host recognition when scheme is omitted and a leading component separator is present.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (true)
{

    case (preg_match('/google.com$/',$host)):
        echo 'Google';
        break;

    case (preg_match('/google.com\/cars/',$host)):
        echo 'Cars - Google';
        break;

    case (preg_match('/google.com\/bicvcles/',$host)):
        echo 'Bicycles - Google';
        break;

    case (preg_match('/google.com\/trains/',$host)):
        echo 'Trains - Google';
        break;

    default:
        echo "test";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. The only thing is, if I have a dash (-) in the url, it still doesn't work. Does anybody has a solution for this?